# Pjax - PDF Opening in Pjax-Container As Garbage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pjax

I have got Pjax loading the inner content for my site, but for PDFs it fails and seems to try and read the content within the container, rather than forcing it try its default behaviour. Resulting in stuff like this

> %PDF-1.4 %���� 74 0 obj <> endobj xref 74...

http://nti.mywellbeing.org/articles/prioritising-tools-and-techniques and then clicking on the Find Out More button... 
http://ogilvyeast.mywellbeing.org/ckeditor_assets/attachments/14/8C_johari_window.pdf

How can I make pjax fail/default to standard behaviour?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're probably using the pjax-rails gem. In that case just set the `data-skip-pjax` attribute on the PDF link to do a full page load:

```
<a href="/ckeditor_assets/attachments/14/8C_johari_window.pdf" target="_blank" data-skip-pjax="true">Find out more...</a>
```

Or using `link_to`:

```rb
link_to "Find out more...", whatever_path, :target => "_blank", :"data-skip-pjax" => true
```